# QT: Notification after External Drag and Drop

Tags: windows, qt, drag-and-drop, pyqt, pyside

I'm trying to get any kind of notification from qt after a (successful) drag and drop action from a QListView in my application to an external target like the explorer.

Things I've tried so far:

- QDropEvent: seems to only fire from internal widgets.
- mouseReleaseEvent: stops working when I use QDrop
- I tried to set up a mousehook with pyhook to catch the mouse-up after the drag. This works for successful drops but hangs after
  rejected drops

Any pointers would be helpful.

**EDIT**

forgot the code

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import sys
import pyHook 

from PySide import QtGui
from PySide import QtCore

app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)


class MainWidget(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):

        super(MainWidget, self).__init__()

        thumbViewModel = ThumbItemModel([ "item1" , "item2" , "item3" ])
        self.thumbView = ThumbnailView()
        self.thumbView.setModel(thumbViewModel)

        self.hm = pyHook.HookManager()
        self.hm.MouseLeftUp = self.onLeftMouseUp
        self.hm.HookMouse() #this will make the program unresponsive after an unsuccessful drop
        mainLayout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        mainLayout.addWidget(self.thumbView)

        self.setLayout(mainLayout)

        self.show()

    def onLeftMouseUp(self, event):
        print(event.Position)
        return True


class ThumbnailView(QtGui.QListView):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwds):
        super(ThumbnailView, self).__init__(*args, **kwds)

        self.setDragEnabled(True)

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        #only works with setDragEnabled(False)
        print('mouse released')

    def dropEvent(self, event):
        print('dropped')
        return QtGui.QListView.dropEvent(self, event)



    def startDrag(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print('drag started')
        return QtGui.QListView.startDrag(self, *args, **kwargs)



class ThumbItemModel(QtGui.QStringListModel):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwds):
        super(ThumbItemModel, self).__init__(*args, **kwds)


    def supportedDropActions(self): 
        return QtCore.Qt.MoveAction | QtCore.Qt.CopyAction         

    def flags(self, index):
        if not index.isValid():
            return QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEnabled
        return QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEnabled | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsSelectable | \
               QtCore.Qt.ItemIsDragEnabled | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsDropEnabled        

    def mimeTypes(self):
        return ['text/uri-list', 'text/plain']

    def mimeData(self, indexes):
        mimedata = QtCore.QMimeData()
        fakeFile = 'file:///C:/matToObj.ms'
        mimedata.setData('text/uri-list', QtCore.QByteArray(fakeFile))
        return mimedata

    def dropMimeData(self, data, action, row, column, parent):
        print('dropMimeData %s %s %s %s' % (data.data('text/uri-list'), action, row, parent))
        return True


widget = MainWidget()
widget.show()

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Can you show a code example of what you have tried so far?

Comment: This link might give you some help [link](http://blogao.googlecode.com/hg/lib/qtjambi-win32-lgpl-4.5.2_01/doc/html/com/trolltech/qt/qtjambi-dnd.html)

Comment: No, sorry, as far as I can tell it doesn't say anything about events after external drops

Comment: Have you tried setAcceptDrops() on the widget? Drag and drop externally works in my app: https://github.com/jeremysanders/veusz/blob/master/windows/mainwindow.py

Comment: That only enables dropping on the widget. I need a way to fire an event for a drop outside of my application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the pyHook stuff, then add to the `ThumbnailView` class something along the lines of:

```
    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        if (event.button() == QtCore.Qt.LeftButton):
            self.dragStartPosition = event.pos()

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        if (not (event.buttons() & QtCore.Qt.LeftButton)):
            return
        if ((event.pos() - self.dragStartPosition).manhattanLength() < QtGui.QApplication.startDragDistance()):
            return

        drag = QtGui.QDrag(self)
        mimeData = QtCore.QMimeData()

        mimeData.setData('text/uri-list', 'file:///C:/matToObj.ms')
        drag.setMimeData(mimeData)

        dropAction = drag.exec_(QtCore.Qt.CopyAction | QtCore.Qt.MoveAction)
        print 'dropped: %d'%dropAction
```

`dropAction` will contain a value that indicates whether the drop failed or was accepted, as listed here: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qt.html#DropAction-enum (page for c++, pretty easy to translate to Python)

Note that this code is based on an example here: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/dnd.html#dragging

Obviously you'd probably want to extend it so that the mime data actually contained a path that depended on the particular item that was being dragged at the time! You might also want to change what you pass to `drag.exec_()`